# Set my search page results in sharepoint 2010

Tags: search, settings

For several days I battle with the search engine.

I would like create my own results page (`mycustomresults.aspx`) but I don't know how and where to change this page?

I would like to see a new field.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you create one search center and link it to the Search Service Application as the global search center. In the pages library of that site collection you create your custom pages. So this is where your page should be.

Now, having said that, it really depends on your business case and what you are trying to do. I have clients with search pages all over the place for specific reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Hi and thanks a lot for having replying.

I "want" to create a specific search (with a own display template) for a subsite of a site collection. Possible ? I saw I can do it with a search site (base or entreprise) but my requests will concern the entire site collection.

Best regards.